# How do I pick a well drilling company?

Tags: water, well

It seems like well drilling comes down to them showing up and charging you for time and potentially materials. If they drill a dry well, you pay for that. I live in a rural area and am looking at putting a well onto an unimproved lot. My state keeps track of all wells drilled, so I think the depth will be between 400' and 600' feet. There are three different drillers that have done these wells in my area.

How should I pick between the three? What types of questions should I ask, is there anything I should make sure is in place? I'm worried that I'm just writing an open check once the drillers are onsite.

Comment: Check with neighbors to see who they've used. Make sure you ask the companies for references when you invite them in for a bid, and be sure you check with the references to ensure they felt they got a fair deal & weren't over billed. With 3 companies local, there's probably not going to be a significant difference in price unless they charge for travel from their place to yours and one is a lot closer than the others.

Comment: Check with the state office that tracks the wells. They may be able to give you some unbiased advice on locating the well to minimize the chances of the first hole coming up dry. (Of course, that's _advice_, not a _guarantee_...)

Comment: read online reviews from google, yelp, etc, then consider price to break the tie between the better two.

Comment: I would check if there team includes a Water witch, deviner, I used to think these were bunk. My dad had purchased a tract of property before he passed and after 2 dry wells my grampa paid a friend that went out with wire rods he marked 6 places 1 on each plot and all of them produced water,  I did not believe it and I watched him walk the property I have only drilled a few since then in Oregon where you are just about guaranteed water but on 1 mountain location we used a driller that said he would find water or not drill he hit water on the first hole. So limited but good experience for me.